# secure an angular route more safely than with routeguard?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, routes

I have to create a SPA with Angular 8.

In the SPA I will have a component with a form that can only be seen if the user has permissions.

For this I had planned to use a route guard, the problem is that the guard runs in the client's browser, which does not guarantee that the component of the form is not seen by a malicious user (for example, editing the js).

There will be security in the RestAPI backend when receiving the form data (permission check and so on), but I need to make sure that the form cannot be seen by anyone who does not have permissions.

Is there a way to efficiently block the visualization of an angular component?

Comment: Just hide the visuals of the empty form? If this malicious user got past the router guard but not the server side authentication then they won't see any data.

Comment: You can have a look at lazy load in Angular. Basically you just need to put the form into a separate user only module. After the user is authenticated, you then load the form. BTW, the same question yesterday was downvoted twice but this one has got one upvote which is crazy!

Comment: @Steve What do you mean by hiding the visuals? hide them using javascript or something similar?

Comment: @Antediluvian The module loaded with lazy loading is not stored on the client side too?

Comment: @RangerCode Not until the lazy loader loads it.

Comment: @RangerCode, maybe that was just a lazy interpretation of " efficiently block the visualization...". I took that to mean: prevent the (empty) form from showing

Comment: You can implement http interceptor and check permissions if user access and tried to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

There is no denying that you client side code can not be accessed by malicious code alteration.

You can not do anything about it, as SPA code relies on front end so if you know the variables and can alter the functions from lets say console or otherwise, there is nothing you can do.

As far the access control goes or blocking UI elements goes, you can have strong back-end which will not authorized unauthorized access. This way only UI can be seen but the data required to function that UI will not be visible (due to back-end access control).

You can think it in logical way,

1. If the sensitive data is not visible then no problem if UI element is visible.
2. If some action button is visible to malicious user, as to perform this action you need back-end, this won't work as the malicious use wont have access to end endpoint.

Bottom line is  your band-end should be very strong to handle authorized requests and separate itself from unauthorized requests.